# Find position of first value greater than 0 in column A and return value in that position in column B

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I'm new in R and I'm struggling with this problem: I want to evaluate values in column A and get the position of the first non-zero value in that column. Then, I want to obtain the value in the position found but in column B. This would need to happen in a data frame similar to this one.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 1998 |
| 0 | 1997 |
| 2 | 1996 |
| 3 | 1995 |

So the output should be: 1996.

I've tried using match() without success. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

If your A is nonnegative

```
B[ match(FALSE, cummax(A) == 0) ]
```

Answer (score 4):

The existing answers are both great. Just thought I'd round this out with a tidyverse method that's quite readable:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
    filter(`Column A` > 0) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    pull(`Column B`)
```

Data:

```
dat <- tribble(
    ~`Column A`, ~`Column B`,
    0,         1998,
    0,         1997,
    2,         1996,
    3,         1995
)
```

Comment: Less readable but shorter: `dat %>% filter(`Column A` > 0) %>% `[[`(1, "Column B")`. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

We can use `base R` functions i.e. `with` - create a logical condition with 'Column A', subset the corresponding elements of 'Column B' where the logical condition is TRUE, and use indexing `[1]` to return the first element

```
with(df1, `Column B`[`Column A` > 0][1])
```

---

If the column name is stored in another object

```
obj1 <- 'Column A'
df1[["Column B"]][df1[[obj1]] > 0][1]
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! Just for reference in case somebody like me is reading this, if you don't specify [1], it will return a vector instead of just the first value.

Answer (score 3):

Another base R option

```
with(
  df,
  ColumnB[which.min(ColumnA <= 0)]
)
```

which gives

```
[1] 1996
```